# express statement in first order logic

Tags: logic

I am looking to express the following statement in first-order logic, however I am unsure where to start.

```
Nobody likes everyone else
```

Where the domain is all people.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lnot \exists x \forall y (x \ne y \to Likes(x,y))$.

"Nobody" means "no one"; thus : $\lnot \exists x$.

"Every one else" means "all people different from the previous one" (we admit that everyone likes himself); thus : $\forall y \text { such that } x \ne y$.